# Manually create a 301 redirect in Apache to redirect all IP requests for the site to it's correct domain name

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services

When I search on Google for betterlifeportal, it is displaying IP Addresses instead of Domain name for some of the pages. Is there a way we can manually create a 301 redirect in Apache to redirect all IP requests for the site to it's correct domain name. Or is there a plugin that can help me?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options. These are a few that come to mind:

1. By configuring apache: Create an additional apache vhost which is only used with the correct URL (see [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html)). In the default vhost configuration (i.e. the first one), redirect all wrong URLs to the correct domain, e.g. by using the [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive or [`mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).
2. Since you have tagged your question with 'amazon-web-services', I am assuming you are running your service on AWS. You could create a [CloudFront distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/de/cloudfront/) that only allows your domain in front of your service, thus ensuring that only users (and web crawlers like Google) using the correct domain reach your website